# How to manage Sitecore security access rights settings(configurations) on items?

Tags: security, sitecore, tds

As documentation states security settings on items are kept as text definition on each items.

We have huge tree with a lot of items, I addition exist more than 30 roles. The challenge we face is how to manage the security settings on all items and promote them between environments (Dev, TEST, UAT, Prod). We are using  TFS and TDS (team development for Sitecore) but as out-of-box system works all security configurations are part of the items.

Let say we want to change security access for particular Role on selected items. This means we have to make the changes in TDS project and redeploy these items to all environments. Is this the correct/recommended approach?
Is there some other way ?

Update:

Particular case. We have operation site in production, where the administrator have changed the initial defined security configurations on item A (introduced new ones or change existing). Some other fields could also be changed.
We are ready to deploy the new developed features in production. One of the new changes is item A - where have been introduced new access rights for some new Role N1. The result we want is to keep all configurations for item A from production and add in addition the new security access rights for Role N1. How can this be achieved?
Redeploying the whole item A means losing the configuration from production.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to re-deploy the items, disregarding whether you use TDS or not. Security settings for items are stored with items in Sitecore architecturally, that's why if the security settings are changed for an item, this literally means the item has changed and should be re-deployed.

In order to minimize the amount of items you have to deploy each time you can:

- **leverage the "inherit" option as much as possible** - as a result, only items with explicit 'allow' or 'deny' permissions are affected
- **assign security for roles, not for users** - as a result, in order to apply permissions for a new user you simply include it into the appropriate roles

Comment: Fair enough. I understand this. I have updated the question with one particular example, in case you can comment on this or refer me to some other info will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The security settings are stored in the item itself, you can see them if you select the "View Standard Fields" option. Usual way to achieve what you want to merge the items back to Dev/QA/Integration, make the changes there and package them into Porduction. Or to make all the changes directly on Production again. This module may help weed out the differences, not sure if it will check Security though: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Compare_Servers.aspx

Comment: @DevUser, I'm not sure it is a good idea to perform some changes to production directly. In this case your pre-production environment and live environment are different, and you can't be sure the changes you introduce work the same way you see it when being tested. It's the same analogy as with publishing - if you modify the items in the web database directory, you'll lose the changes right after the next publishing.

Comment: @ Yan Sklyarenko So, do you mean that NO security access rights configuration should be applied straight on production site by site administrators? Do you mean that security access rights settings must be promote  through packaging systems from Dev –> Test –> Production ?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this, otherwise the changes are not tested. When you allow people changing the production system directly, you take it out of the deployment pipeline, and this means that the production system is in undefined state. I know this sounds like an overhead for such a small thing as access permissions, but even this small change might break a certain functionality which relies on whether the access is allowed or denied.

Comment: I realize that we go out of the scope for this question and that there are different views out there how to handle code/content release management. But cannot stop myself ask:
What do you allow to be change/create/edit on the production system then ?
Highly appreciated if you could point me to some GOOD source of information about that.

Comment: I'm a strong believer that NOTHING should be changed DIRECTLY on a production system passing over pre-production. Production system is assumed to be identical copy of the pre-production, and if e.g. administrator is going to tweak security permissions, he should do this in pre-production, then tests should run (at least, smoke tests) to check nothing was broken by this tiny action, and if the check confirmed it's safe, stage this modification to the production system. Otherwise, how would test it if it's done directly in production? How do you make sure you further changes don't conflict?

Comment: I understand your point. But at the other side Sitecore production system is where the editors create and managing content. 
Does this means that also the content they create also has to be created on pre-production environment, tested there and release to production?

Comment: That's a reasonable question! I think the content editing can be the only exception and should be allowed directly to production. The content validation is a semantic thing and is done by the properly tuned workflow. But you'll have to manage the way to update the production database without vanishing the production content.